# OSMDroid android app zoom in without changing tiles, is it possible?

Tags: openstreetmap, android, tile-server, osmdroid

I am developing an android mobile mapping app using OSMDroid 4.3.  I have established a basemap using arcgisonline as my tile server.

```
String[] urlArray = {"http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/"};
mapView.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("ArcGisOnline", null, 0, 16, 256, "",
        urlArray) {
        @Override
        public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
            String mImageFilenameEnding = ".png";
            return getBaseUrl() + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "/" + aTile.getY() + "/" + aTile.getX()
                    + mImageFilenameEnding;
        }
});
```

Tile server works fine.  When zooming in (level 14+), the tile set with satellite imagery has clouds that partially cover the ground.  I need to find out if it is possible to zoom in without changing tile set.

[image: satellite imagery with cloud cover]

ZOOM level 13

[image: zoom13]

FAKE zoom simulation 
I would lose definition by "blowing up" tile imagery, that is a given, but it is perfectly ok for my purposes.

[image: digital/fake zoom]

Comment: I know when I dealt with ThinkGeo's API, I was able to just disable the web call that tried to load the new tiles.  This let me zoom in further to the last tiles I rendered.  The only disadvantage was that eventually (~2 more levels in) I started seeing the checkerboard tile patterns where my larger tiles separated and had whitespace in between.  You may be able to use that strategy to see what you come up with.  Just intercept the calls after a certain level.

Comment: i'm using osmdroid.  but i'll try and see if there's anything any way to disable tile layer change.